# FuncAnimation with multiple particles

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, particles

Below is a model that I have been working on for a few weeks now, slowly adding more complexity as I learn how to code (coding newbie). If it is not clear, I am trying to create a model of particles of 2 different densities that settle according to stokes settling velocity (as a function of concentration). I am having trouble getting the animation to work with the second particle (working code with one animated particle at the bottom). I have broken out the variables for the two different particles in an attempt to debug the code, but have not had any luck determining what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
import pdb
from scipy import spatial
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

n = 100
n2 = 50
sigma = 0.01
sigma2 = 0.01

pp = 2.56 # pp = particle density (Sphene=3.53) #(Feldspar=2.56) 
#(g/cm^3)

pp2 = 3.53

pf = 2.7 # pf = fluid density(g/cm^3)

pf2 = 2.7

g = 9.8 # g = gravity (m/s^2)

g2 = 9.8

r = 0.003 # r = radius of sphere (meter)

r2 = 0.0002

mu = 0.53 # mu = dynamic viscosity of fluid (log10Poise)

mu2 = 0.53

rp = 0.01 #radius around particle to check for nearest neighbor

rp2 = 0.001

dt = 0.008

dt2 = 0.008

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

az = plt.axes(xlim=(-.5, .5), ylim=(-1, 0))

xdata, ydata = [0.0], [0.0]

xdata2, ydata2 = [0.0], [0.0]

ln, = plt.plot([], [], marker= 'o', 
markerfacecolor='r',markeredgecolor='k', linestyle='None', 
animated=True)

ln2, = plt.plot([], [], marker= 's', 
markerfacecolor='b',markeredgecolor='k', linestyle='None', 
animated=True)

#pdb.set_trace()
def v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu):
    top=2*(pp-pf)*g*(r**2)
    bottom=9*mu
    ws=top/bottom
    return ws

def v_stokes2(pp2,pf2,g2,r2,mu2):
    top2=2*(pp2-pf2)*g2*(r2**2)
    bottom2=9*mu2
    ws2=top2/bottom2
    return ws2


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(  -2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 0)
    return ln, ln2,

def concentration(xdata, ydata, rp):
    coords = list(zip(xdata, ydata))
    tree = spatial.KDTree(coords)
    test = np.column_stack([xdata, ydata])
    nnl = tree.query_ball_point(test, rp) #nearest neighbors as a list 
    #(had tree in here before test but shape was wrong)
    #pdb.set.trace()
    nnt = np.zeros(len(nnl)) #nearest neighbors total
    for i in range(len(nnt)): 
        nnt[i] = len(nnl[i])
    return nnt

def concentration2(xdata2, ydata2, rp2):
    coords2 = list(zip(xdata2, ydata2))
    tree2 = spatial.KDTree(coords2)
    test2 = np.column_stack([xdata2, ydata2])
    nnl2 = tree2.query_ball_point(test2, rp2)  
    nnt2 = np.zeros(len(nnl2)) #nearest neighbors total
    for i in range(len(nnt2)): 
        nnt2[i] = len(nnl2[i])
    return nnt2

#y0 = []
#y1 = []
#y2 = []
#y3 = []
#y4 = []
def update(frame):

    global xdata
    global ydata
    global concentration, v_stokes, pp, pf, g, r, mu, rp, dt, n, sigma

    xdata = xdata + np.random.normal(0, sigma, n)

    wss = v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu)

    if frame == 0.0:
        ydata = np.zeros(len(xdata)) #makes the ydata length = xdata at 
        #time 0 print(ydata)
        rp = 0.003

    if frame > 10:
        rp = 0.008

    cp = concentration(xdata, ydata, rp)
    if np.any(cp == 1):
        cp = cp-1

    if frame > 0.0:
        #y0.append(ydata)
        #y1.append(wss)
        #y2.append(cp)
        #y3.append(dt)
        #y4.append(xdata)
        ydata = ydata + (wss*(1-cp)**3) - dt # [0] 
        for v in ydata:
            if v < -1.001:
                ydata = -1
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,


def update2(frame2):

    global xdata2
    global ydata2
    global concentration2, v_stokes2, pp2, pf2, g2, r2, mu2, rp2, dt2, 
    n2, sigma2

    xdata2 = xdata2 + np.random.normal(0, sigma2, n2)

    wss2 = v_stokes2(pp2,pf2,g2,r2,mu2)

    if frame2 == 0.0:
        ydata2 = np.zeros(len(xdata2)) #makes the ydata length = xdata 
        #at time 0 print(ydata)
        rp2 = 0.003

    if frame2 > 10:
        rp2 = 0.008

    cp2 = concentration2(xdata2, ydata2, rp2)
    if np.any(cp2 == 1):
        cp2 = cp2-1

    if frame2 > 0.0:
        #y5.append(ydata2)
        #y6.append(wss2)
        #y7.append(cp2)
        #y8.append(dt2)
        #y9.append(xdata2)

        ydata2 = ydata2 + (wss2*(1-cp2)**3) - dt2 # [0] 
        for v2 in ydata2:
            if v2 < -1.001:
                ydata2 = -1

     ln2.set_data(xdata2, ydata2)
     return ln2,

def update_all(i):
    l1 = update(i)
    l2 = update2(i)
    return l1, l2,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_all, frames=range(0,200),
                    init_func=init, blit=True, interval=100, repeat = 
False)
# change frames=range(0:1000) to change the number of frames 

plt.show()
```

**Below is the original working code with one animated particle:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
import pdb
from scipy import spatial
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

n=100
sigma= 0.01


#m = np.random.uniform(n)

pp = 2.56 # pp = particle density (Sphene=3.53) #(Feldspar=2.56) 
#(g/cm^3)

pf = 2.7 # pf = fluid density(g/cm^3)

g = 9.8 # g = gravity (m/s^2)

r = 0.003 # r = radius of sphere (meter)

mu = 0.53 # mu = dynamic viscosity of fluid (log10Poise)

rp = 0.01 #radius around particle to check for nearest neighbor

dt =0.008

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
az = plt.axes(xlim=(-.5, .5), ylim=(-1, 0))
xdata, ydata = [0.0], [0.0]
ln, = plt.plot([], [], marker= 'o', 
markerfacecolor='r',markeredgecolor='k', linestyle='None', 
animated=True)

#pdb.set_trace()
def v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu):
    top=2*(pp-pf)*g*(r**2)
    bottom=9*mu
    ws=top/bottom
    return ws


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(  -2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 0)
    return ln,

def concentration(xdata, ydata, rp):
    coords = list(zip(xdata, ydata))
    tree = spatial.KDTree(coords)
    test = np.column_stack([xdata, ydata])
    nnl = tree.query_ball_point(test, rp) #nearest neighbors as a list 
    #(had tree in here before test but shape was wrong)
    #pdb.set.trace()
    nnt = np.zeros(len(nnl)) #nearest neighbors total
    for i in range(len(nnt)): 
        nnt[i] = len(nnl[i])
    return nnt

y0 = []
y1 = []
y2 = []
y3 = []
y4 = []
def update(frame):

    global xdata
    global ydata
    global concentration, v_stokes, pp, pf, g, r, mu, rp, dt, n

    xdata = xdata + np.random.normal(0, sigma, n)

    wss = v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu)
    #print(wss)

    if frame == 0.0:
        ydata = np.zeros(len(xdata)) #makes the ydata length = xdata at 
        #time 0 print(ydata)
        rp = 0.003

    if frame > 10:
        rp = 0.008

    if frame > 30:
        rp = 0.01

    if frame > 50: #notice that the particles move up instead of just 
    #slowing down
        rp = 0.013

    cp = concentration(xdata, ydata, rp)
    #print(cp)
    if np.any(cp == 1):
    cp = cp-1
    #print(xdata)
    print(cp)
    if frame > 0.0:
        y0.append(ydata)
        y1.append(wss)
        y2.append(cp)
        y3.append(dt)
        y4.append(xdata)
        ydata = ydata + (wss*(1-cp)**3) - dt # [0] 
        for v in ydata:
            if v < -1.001:
                ydata = -1
        #if np.all(ydata) > 0:
            #print(ydata)
            #print(frame)
    #print(ydata[0:5])
    #ydata = ydata + (wss*(1-cp))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

#print(test)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(0,200),
                init_func=init, blit=True, interval=100, repeat = 
False)
# change frames=range(0:1000) to change the number of frames 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, ...)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) expects as its second argument a callable (e.g. a function) to update the plot.

> `func` : callable
>   The function to call at each frame. The first argument will be the next value in frames. Any additional positional arguments can be supplied via the fargs parameter.

If you have two functions to update, you would need to merge them into one,

```
def update_all(i):
    l1 = update(i)
    l2 = update2(i)
    return l1,l2

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_all, frames=range(0,200), init_func=init, ...)
```

Mind that you need to define the `plot`s in the same manner as usual, `ln, = plt.plot` and that you need to return the line object itself in the two updating functions.

Complete running code:

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from scipy import spatial

n=100
sigma= 0.01
pp = 2.56 # pp = particle density (Sphene=3.53) #(Feldspar=2.56) 
#(g/cm^3)
pp2 = 3.53
pf = 2.7 # pf = fluid density(g/cm^3)
pf2 = 2.7
g = 9.8 # g = gravity (m/s^2)
g2 = 9.8
r = 0.003 # r = radius of sphere (meter)
r2 = 0.0002
mu = 0.53 # mu = dynamic viscosity of fluid (log10Poise)
mu2 = 0.53
rp = 0.01 #radius around particle to check for nearest neighbor
rp2 = 0.001
dt = 0.008
dt2 = 0.008

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

az = plt.axes(xlim=(-.5, .5), ylim=(-1, 0))

xdata, ydata = [0.0], [0.0]
xdata2, ydata2 = [0.0], [0.0]

ln, = plt.plot([], [], marker= 'o', 
               markerfacecolor='r',markeredgecolor='k', linestyle='None', 
               animated=True)

ln2, = plt.plot([], [], marker= 's', 
                markerfacecolor='b',markeredgecolor='k', linestyle='None', 
                animated=True)

#pdb.set_trace()
def v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu):
    top=2*(pp-pf)*g*(r**2)
    bottom=9*mu
    ws=top/bottom
    return ws

def v_stokes2(pp2,pf2,g2,r2,mu2):
    top2=2*(pp2-pf2)*g2*(r2**2)
    bottom2=9*mu2
    ws2=top2/bottom2
    return ws2


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(  -2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 0)
    return ln, ln2

def concentration(xdata, ydata, rp):
    coords = list(zip(xdata, ydata))
    tree = spatial.KDTree(coords)
    test = np.column_stack([xdata, ydata])
    nnl = tree.query_ball_point(test, rp)  
    nnt = np.zeros(len(nnl)) #nearest neighbors total
    for i in range(len(nnt)): 
        nnt[i] = len(nnl[i])
    return nnt

def concentration2(xdata2, ydata2, rp2):
    coords2 = list(zip(xdata2, ydata2))
    tree2 = spatial.KDTree(coords2)
    test2 = np.column_stack([xdata2, ydata2])
    nnl2 = tree2.query_ball_point(test2, rp2) 
    nnt2 = np.zeros(len(nnl2)) #nearest neighbors total
    for i in range(len(nnt2)): 
        nnt2[i] = len(nnl2[i])
    return nnt2

y0 = [];y1 = [];y2 = [];y3 = [];y4 = []

def update(frame):

    global xdata
    global ydata
    global concentration, v_stokes, pp, pf, g, r, mu, rp, dt, n

    xdata = xdata + np.random.normal(0, sigma, n)

    wss = v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu)

    if frame == 0.0:
        ydata = np.zeros(len(xdata)) #makes the ydata length = xdata at 
        #time 0 print(ydata)
        rp = 0.003

    if frame > 10:
        rp = 0.008

    if frame > 30:
        rp = 0.01

    if frame > 50: #notice that the particles move up instead of just 
    #slowing down
        rp = 0.013

    cp = concentration(xdata, ydata, rp)
    if np.any(cp == 1):
        cp = cp-1
    #print(cp)
    if frame > 0.0:
        y0.append(ydata)
        y1.append(wss)
        y2.append(cp)
        y3.append(dt)
        y4.append(xdata)
        ydata = ydata + (wss*(1-cp)**3) - dt # [0] 
        for j,v in enumerate(ydata):
            if v < -1.001:
                ydata[j] = -1
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln


def update2(frame2):

    global xdata2
    global ydata2
    global concentration2, v_stokes, pp2, pf2, g2, r2, mu2, rp2, dt2, n

    xdata2 = xdata2 + np.random.normal(0, sigma, n)

    wss2 = v_stokes2(pp2,pf2,g2,r2,mu2)

    if frame2 == 0.0:
        ydata2 = np.zeros(len(xdata2)) #makes the ydata length = xdata 
        #at time 0 print(ydata)
        rp2 = 0.003

    if frame2 > 10:
        rp2 = 0.008

    if frame2 > 30:
        rp2 = 0.01

    if frame2 > 50: #notice that the particles move up instead of just 
    #slowing down
        rp2 = 0.013

    cp2 = concentration2(xdata2, ydata2, rp2)
    if np.any(cp2 == 1):
        cp2 = cp2-1

    if frame2 > 0.0:
        y0.append(ydata2)
        y1.append(wss2)
        y2.append(cp2)
        y3.append(dt2)
        y4.append(xdata2)
        ydata2 = ydata2 + (wss2*(1-cp2)**3) - dt2 # [0] 
        for j,v in enumerate(ydata2):
            if v < -1.001:
                ydata2[j] = -1

    ln2.set_data(xdata2, ydata2)
    return ln2

def update_all(i):
    l1 = update(i)
    l2 = update2(i)
    return l1,l2

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_all, frames=range(0,200),
                    init_func=init, blit=True, interval=100, repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

Since the code seems mostly redundant for the two particle classes, I would suggest to simplify it by putting it into a class.

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from scipy import spatial

n=100
sigma= 0.01
pp = 2.56 # pp = particle density (Sphene=3.53) #(Feldspar=2.56) 
#(g/cm^3)
pp2 = 3.53
pf = 2.7 # pf = fluid density(g/cm^3)
pf2 = 2.7
g = 9.8 # g = gravity (m/s^2)
g2 = 9.8
r = 0.003 # r = radius of sphere (meter)
r2 = 0.0002
mu = 0.53 # mu = dynamic viscosity of fluid (log10Poise)
mu2 = 0.53
rp = 0.01 #radius around particle to check for nearest neighbor
rp2 = 0.001
dt = 0.008
dt2 = 0.008


class Particles():
    def __init__(self,ax, xdata,
                 pp, pf, g, r, mu, rp, dt, n,
                 marker="o",mfc="r"):
        self.xdata=xdata
        self.ydata = np.zeros(len(self.xdata))
        self.pp=pp;self.pf=pf;self.g=g;self.r=r;self.mu=mu
        self.rp=rp;self.dt=dt;self.n=n
        self.ln, = ax.plot([], [], marker= marker, 
               markerfacecolor=mfc,markeredgecolor='k', linestyle='None', 
               animated=True)
           
    def v_stokes(self, pp,pf,g,r,mu):
        top=2*(pp-pf)*g*(r**2)
        bottom=9*mu
        return top/bottom
    
    def concentration(self,xdata, ydata, rp):
        coords = list(zip(xdata, ydata))
        tree = spatial.KDTree(coords)
        test = np.column_stack([xdata, ydata])
        nnl = tree.query_ball_point(test, rp)  
        nnt = np.zeros(len(nnl)) #nearest neighbors total
        for i in range(len(nnt)): 
            nnt[i] = len(nnl[i])
        return nnt
    
    def update(self, frame):
        self.xdata += np.random.normal(0, sigma, n)
        if frame == 0:
            self.ydata = np.zeros(len(self.xdata))
    
        wss = self.v_stokes(self.pp,self.pf,self.g,self.r,self.mu)

        cp = self.concentration(self.xdata, self.ydata, self.rp)
        if np.any(cp == 1):
            cp = cp-1

        if frame > 0.0:
            self.ydata += (wss*(1-cp)**3) - dt 
            for j,v in enumerate(self.ydata):
                if v < -1.001:
                    self.ydata[j] = -1
        self.ln.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata)
        return self.ln

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xdata, xdata2 = [0.0], [0.0]

p1 = Particles(ax,xdata, pp, pf, g, r, mu, rp, dt, n,
                 marker="o",mfc="r")
p2 = Particles(ax,xdata2, pp2, pf2, g2, r2, mu2, rp2, dt2, n,
                 marker="s",mfc="b")

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return p1.ln, p2.ln

def update(i):
    l1 = p1.update(i)
    l2 = p2.update(i)
    return l1, l2

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(0,200),
                    init_func=init, blit=True, interval=100, repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance again @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have attempted to merge the two functions (into `update_all`)as you have mentioned and defined 2 plots `ln,` and `ln2,` however, nothing seems to be plotting and there are no errors being thrown. Any other suggestions? I can throw up the new code if that helps?

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, The bottom code looks super clean, hopefully, I will get to this level of coding in the future (a long way out!). However, after importing them into python, neither of them is running. Any suggestions? no errors are being thrown.

Comment: Did I make a mistake formatting the code?! I updated the answer inserting it again, can you recheck? If it is then still not working I would need to know how you run it, and what versions you are using.

Comment: Now if I wanted to make all of my particles (both sizes) settle as a function of the concentration of all particles around them (red and blue) can I combine the `def concentration` for the two?? Or is there a better way? As of now, I have 2 independent sample populations that are not interacting with each other, which is meaningless if I am assessing hindered settling. -Thanks

Comment: I don't think I can solve your physics problem here for you.

Comment: I am not sure its a physics problem or requires much solving, as the `def concentration` is already taking into account the concentration of particles within radius 'r'. From a beginners standpoint, I think combining the two `def concentration`s into one function that adds together the particle concentrations e.g.                                   `nnn = nnt, nnt2 `                                                                                     `return nnn ` seems like it should work. Just curious if you had a suggestion about this. -Thanks